# Cannot access Properties value in MSTest

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest, testcontext

I'm actually facing an issue using TestContext in MSTest. When I add a property to the context, it doesn't exist when I try to get it in another test method. Can someone explain me why or know how to fix it?
Here is my code sample:

I can't get why i can Console.Writeline the value I need in Action1() but can't access it in Action2()

Thanks :)

```
namespace API.Tests.Controllers
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ControllerTests
    {
        private SomeController _controller;
        private SomeService _somService;
        public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            _someService = new SomeService();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Action2()
        {
            // Arrange
            var criteria = TestContext.Properties["id"]; <-- Can't access value here, it doesn't exist

            SomeController _controller = new SomeController(_someService);

            // Act
            IHttpActionResult result = _controller.Search((string)criteria);

            // Assert
            var contentResult = result as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<Object>>;

            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result,typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<Object>>));
        }

        
        [TestMethod]
        public void Action1()
        {
            // Arrange
            var testObj = new Obj
            {
                id = 10,
                name = "Test",
                code = "XXX"
            };

            SomeController _controller = new SomeController(_someService);

            // Act
            IHttpActionResult result = _controller.Create(testObj);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<int>));

            var content = result as OkNegotiatedContentResult<int>;

            TestContext.Properties.Clear();
            TestContext.Properties.Add("id", content.Content.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine(TestContext.Properties["id"]); <-- I can get the value here
            Console.WriteLine(TestContext.Properties.Count); <-- equal to 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Introducing dependencies between tests is a really bad idea. Every test should be independent. Why do you have two tests at all? Seems like you could write it as a single test instead. Alternativly why not just use a static id for your `Action2`-test instead of relying on the outcome of `Action1`?

Comment: Hello! I need to get the id returned by Action1 to put it as parameter for Action2, I'm making checks in database after that in my scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coupling tests is a really bad idea and introduces many problems that are hard to find. In particular you cannot execute `Action2` without executing `Action1`, as you already noticed.

However it's not entirely clear what your SuT is supposed to do and what you want to test. It seems your test is some integration-test that verifies a specific sequence of calls to your service-endoints. So your endpoints depend on one another in some way. Instead of splitting those calls into different tests, you can just create a *single* test and call your actions there. In your case it seems you want to test if you can *search* a resource that you *created* before using the `Search`- and `Create`-endpoint respectivly. So just use a *single* test that calls both those endpoints.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Action1()
{
    // Arrange
    var testObj = new Obj
    {
        id = 10,
        name = "Test",
        code = "XXX"
    };

    SomeController _controller = new SomeController(_someService);

    // Act
    IHttpActionResult result = _controller.Create(testObj);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<int>));

    var content = result as OkNegotiatedContentResult<int>;

    // Act
    IHttpActionResult result2 = _controller.Search(content.Content.ToString());

    // Assert
    var contentResult = result2 as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<Object>>;

    Assert.IsNotNull(result2);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result2, typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<Object>>));
}
```

If this is more some unit-test, you should consider to fake the dependency, e.g. by mocking the creation of the resource and then call the `Search`-endpoint on that fake-instance. However I'd argue mocking your SuT is also a bad idea and often shows that it is doing to many things.

Comment: Yes I'm actually trying to write some intergration tests more than unit-test, had the idea of running everything in a single test for all the feature but didn't know if it was okay doing it